# Kotlin multiplatform lambda call without Unit return type

Tags: ios, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native

I have a multiplatform Kotlin project for Android and iOS. The functions in common module are written like this:

```py
fun test(successCallback: (String) -> Unit, errorCallback: (Error) -> Unit) {
    successCallback("success")
}
```

Android usage of function:

```
Common.test(successCallback = { 
                Log.d(TAG, it) 
            },
            errorCallback = {
                Log.d(TAG, it)
            }
})
```

iOS usage of function:

```
Common.test(successCallback: { it in
                print(it)
                return KotlinUnit()
            }, errorCallback: { error in
                print(error)
                return KotlinUnit()
            })
```

JVM world seems to handle the return type (Unit) by itself (nothing needs to be returned), while you must return `KotlinUnit()` in iOS.

I would like to achieve the same on iOS (callback without `return KotlinUnit()`)

Comment: I don't think that this is possible. Implicit return of `Unit` is a feature of the kotlin compiler. When using Java, you'd also have to `return Unit.INSTANCE`

Comment: Maybe this can be solved by using an interface instead of a functional type. `interface Consumer<T> { operator fun invoke(t: T) }`

Comment: See https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/pull/2968 which will be merged in upcoming Kotlin/Native release.